# What is the difference between <copy-of> and <apply-templates>?

Tags: xslt

When should I use `<copy-of>` instead of `<apply-templates>`?

What is their unique role? Most of the time replacing `<apply-templates>` with `<copy-of>` gives out weird output. Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- **`xsl:copy-of`** is an exact copy of the matched input xml element. No xslt processing takes place and the output from that element will be exactly the same as the input.
- **`xsl:apply-templates`** tells the xslt engine to process templates that match the selected elements. `xsl:apply-templates` is what gives xslt its overriding capability, since the templates you create with match on elements can have different priorities, and the template with the highest priority will be executed.

Input:

```
<a>
   <b>asdf</b>
   <b title="asdf">asdf</b>
</a>
```

Xslt 1:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... >
   <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:copy-of select="b" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Xml output 1:

```
<b>asdf</b>
<b title="asdf">asdf</b>
```

Xslt 2:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... >
   <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="b" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="b" priority="0">
        <b><xsl:value-of select="." /></b>
        <c><xsl:value-of select="." /></c>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="b[@title='asdf']" priority="1">
       <b title="{@title}"><xsl:value-of select="@title" /></b>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Xml output 2:

```
<b>asdf</b>
<c>asdf</c>
<b title="asdf">asdf</b>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
copy-of
```

will simply return you a dump of the XML in the supplied node-set

```
apply-templates
```

on the other hand will apply any templates applicable to the node-set passed it.