# Xslt transforming xsd into xsd : priority rule to avoid

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm trying to use xslt to change a XML schema to another.
I just have some trouble of priority in one of my change. 
I would like to add to my first schema an element in a sequence and add an attribute to elements which already exist. I want also to add an attributeGroup before the  (end of the complexType's tag).
I succeed to create separatively both transformation but it does not work together because of the priority.

Here is the add of my attributeGroup :

```
  <xsl:template match="xsd:complexType">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:element name="xsd:attributeGroup">
            <xsl:attribute name="ref">attributsXrm</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

And here is the add of my element "balisesXrm" :

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:element">
        <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
            <xsl:attribute name="ref">balisesXrmType</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="maxOccurs">unbounded</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()| @*[not(name() = 'maxOccurs')]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

When i launch my transformation, I only get the attributsXrm created (because complexType is before element in my work even if my complexType's name is deleted, I don't know why) as you can see here :

```
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="refid" type="xsd:QName"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:attributeGroup ref="attributsXrm"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I would like to get :

```
<xsd:complexType name="typeAssociation">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="refid" type="xsd:QName"/>
        <xsd:element ref="balisesXrm">
    </xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:attributeGroup ref="attributsXrm"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I let you see my input XSD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="3.2.1ec" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsd:complexType name="typeAssociation">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="refid" type="xsd:QName"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I can't find a way to put both transformation in the same template with `apply-templates` for example. 
Hope somebody can help me,
Regards.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your input XSD. Note that, I think all you probably want to change ` <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates />`.

Comment: I will edit my post but you were right, I will try to understand better how apply-templates works ! Anyway, thanks a lot, @Tim C. The only problem is my complexType's name is deleted by the transformation, i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the problem is with your use of `xsl:copy-of` in your template matching `xsd:complexType`. The `xsl:copy-of` instruction simply copies the selected node without any further transformation. You need to use `xsl:apply-templates` to instead to allow the XSLT engine to continue processing and match templates for the selected elements.

Try this XSLT (which I have also simplified to remove the use of `xsl:element`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsd:complexType">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="attributsXrm" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsd:element">
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()| @*[not(name() = 'maxOccurs')]" />
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element ref="balisesXrmType"></xsd:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Read up on `copy-of` vs `apply-templates` here: [XSLT: what is the difference between <copy-of> and <apply-templates>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859166/xslt-what-is-the-difference-between-copy-of-and-apply-templates)